# Sequelize : is there a syntax to filter on a JSON column of a joint table?

Tags: json, sequelize.js, eager-loading

[Sequelize allows to filter on joint tables.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level)

[It also allows (for PostgreSQL, and maybe MySQL) to filter on JSON columns.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html)

**Is there a syntax that works for both at the same time ? A where on a JSON field of a joint table ?**

For example:
If I have a table Author, a table Book with a JSON column "title". In my records, the "title" column generally contains {"fr": "", "en": "en title"}.

Can I get all the authors with at least 1 book whose english title contains "C++" ?

Sincerely,

Ricola3D

Comment: Yes, there is but could you share the model definitions of all tables that is mentioned?

Comment: And to do so you need JSONB and not just JSON column